# vi move cursor to beginning of substitution command

Tags: vim, vi

If I'm doing a long substitution, say:

`:%s/<h3>.*<\/h3>/<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne"><h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="
collapseOne">\1<\/a><\/h4><\/div><div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">/`

And I realize that I forgot the `\(\)` around the `.*`, is there a way to move the cursor back to the beginning of the expression (like control-a on the command line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `home` and `end` keys will move the start and end of the expression in the line editor.

Comment: Perfect!  BTW- my Mac doesn't have a home key, but it can the simulated with fn + ←

Answer (score 4):

You have minimal navigation with the cursor keys and <kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>End</kbd> in the command-line, but for such huge commands, I prefer to switch to *command-line window* by pressing `<C-F>` inside the command-line, or starting the command with `q:` instead of `:`. In that window, you can use all Vim commands for moving and editing, and conclude and execute via `<Enter>`. See `:help q:`.

Comment: Very cool!  I had never seen the command line window before!  :)

Comment: For those trying it out (as I just did), :q while inside the Vi command line closes the command line without quitting Vi.